# WP7 listbox binding not working properly

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

A noob error for sure (I started yesterday afternoon developing in WP7), but I'm wasting a lot time on it.
I post my class and a little part of my code:

```
public class ChronoLaps : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChronoLap> laps = null;

    public int CurrentLap
    {
        get { return lap; }
        set
        {
            if (value == lap) return;
            // Some code here ....
            ChronoLap newlap = new ChronoLap()
            {
                // Some code here ...
            };
            Laps.Insert(0, newlap);

            lap = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentLap");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Laps");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChronoLap> Laps { 
        get { return laps; }
        set
        {
            if (value == laps) return;
            laps = value;
            if (laps != null)
            {
                laps.CollectionChanged += delegate
                {
                    MeanTime = Laps.Sum(p => p.Time.TotalMilliseconds) / (Laps.Count * 1000);
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("MeanTime");
                };
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Laps");
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ChronoLaps History { get; private set; }

    private void butStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        History = new ChronoLaps();
        // History.Laps.Add(new ChronoLap() { Distance = 0 });

        LayoutRoot.DataContext = History;
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>    
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer Margin="-5,13,3,36" Height="758">
                <ListBox Name="lbHistory" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Laps}" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,25,0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lap}" Width="40" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Width="140" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalTime}" Width="140" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Problem is that when I add one or more items to `History.Laps` collection, my listbox is not refreshed and these items don't appear.
But if I remove comment on `// History.Laps.Add(new ChronoLap()...` line, this item appear and so every other inserted later.
More: if I remove that comment and then write `History.Laps.Clear()` (before or after setting binding) binding is not working anymore. It's like it gets crazy if collection is empty.
I really don't understand the reason...

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**:
If i move

```
History = new ChronoLaps();
LayoutRoot.DataContext = History;
```

from `butStart_Click` to `public MainPage()` everything works as expected.
Can someone explain me the reason?

Comment: Can't see anything obvious. Where are you actually setting the value of laps?

Comment: where are you adding the Laps to History?
when adding the Laps, remove the control’s binding before updating the list, and re-apply them afterwards and see

Comment: @Stuart: I'm adding Laps inside my class as showed in my modified question. Remove and re-apply binding? It could be a way, but which is the reason? Thanks

Comment: @Stuart: I've just found a "solution", but I'm not able to understand why it works in this way...

Comment: @marco still don't understand either. Does the same problem occur if you set the page DataContext instead of LayoutRoot?

Comment: @Stuart: yes, same behaviour! It works if I create `History` and set `DataContext` in ctor, but it does not if I set manually on `btnStart_Click`. Don't ask me the reason: I'm a noob facing a too strange problem...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see no point of having a separate class for ChronoLaps. Here is how I modified the code for MainPage.xaml.cs and everything seems to be working for me.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ChronoLap> Laps { get; set; }
        public double MeanTime { get; set; }

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Laps = new ObservableCollection<ChronoLap>();
            Laps.CollectionChanged += delegate
            {
                MeanTime = Laps.Sum(p => p.Time.TotalMilliseconds) / (Laps.Count * 1000);
            };
            DataContext = this;
            Loaded += (s, e) =>
                          {
                              Laps.Add(new ChronoLap() {Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)});
                              Laps.Add(new ChronoLap() {Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)});
                              Laps.Add(new ChronoLap() {Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)});
                          };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer a separate class because my code is cleaner and readable. I'm showing you just a part of the code and it'll be painful for me to transfer "everything" inside main page. Anyway this work exactly as in my example: when I add laps at the beginning (at least one) everything works. I'm confused...

Comment: Can you try initializing private ObservableCollection<ChronoLap> laps = null; (and History  property as well) earlier in mainpage.xaml. Perhaps in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding DataContext and ItemSource for listbox..

How i have done is..

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AppList" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding DisplayItem}" SelectionChanged="AppList_SelectionChanged" Height="500" Width="auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
  </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And i dont know if it will help but still i will just post the code that i am using..

ItemList.cs

```
 
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

namespace AppHouseLibrary
{
    public class ItemList : IComparable
    {
        private string _name;
        public string WidgetName
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private BitmapImage _Icon;
        public BitmapImage Icon
        {
            get
            {
                return _Icon;
            }
            set
            {
                _Icon = value;
            }
        }
        //public string arrow { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage arrow { get; set; }
        public int CompareTo(ItemList other)
        {
            return this.WidgetName.CompareTo(other.WidgetName);
        }
    }
}

I have a UIManager.cs class in which am refreshing the data before i load it on the UI to the user..

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using StirLibrary.com.mportal.data.bean;
using com.mportal.utils;
using StirLibrary.com.mportal.utils;
```

namespace StirLibrary.com.UI
{
    public class UIManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private static UIManager instance = null;
       private static string TAG = "UIManager";
       BitmapImage arrowImage = Utils.returnImage(ImageUtils.ARROW);

```
 public List<ItemList> data = new List<ItemList>();
    public static UIManager getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new UIManager();
        }
        return instance;    
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemList> _displayItem = new ObservableCollection<ItemList>();
    public ObservableCollection<ItemList> DisplayItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _displayItem;
        }
    }

    private UIManager()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
    public WidgetBean[] serviceBeanList = null;
    public WidgetBean[] wheelBeanList = null;

    public WidgetBean getServiceWidgetBean(int selectedIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            if (serviceBeanList != null)
            {
                return serviceBeanList[selectedIndex];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(TAG, e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public WidgetBean getWheelWidgetBean(int selectedIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            if (wheelBeanList != null)
            {
                return wheelBeanList[selectedIndex];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(TAG, e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void DisplayCatalog(string[] ServiceDisplayName, string[] WheelDisplayName, BitmapImage[] ServiceIcons, WidgetBean[] ServiceBeanList, WidgetBean[] WheelBeanList)
    {
        try
        {
            DisplayItem.Clear();
            string disp1 = string.Empty;
            string name = ServiceDisplayName[0];
            wheelBeanList = WheelBeanList;

            serviceBeanList = ServiceBeanList;
            for (int i = 0; i < ServiceDisplayName.Length; i++)
            {
                WidgetBean bean = serviceBeanList[i];
                if (bean.isCategory())
                {
                    DisplayItem.Add(new ItemList { WidgetName = ServiceDisplayName[i], Icon = ServiceIcons[i], arrow = arrowImage });
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayItem.Add(new ItemList { WidgetName = ServiceDisplayName[i], Icon = ServiceIcons[i] });
                }
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("UI");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(TAG,e.Message);
        }
    }


    public void DisplayCatalog(string[] displayName, BitmapImage[] icons, WidgetBean[] beanArray)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceBeanList = beanArray;

            DisplayItem.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < displayName.Length; i++)
            {
                WidgetBean bean = serviceBeanList[i];
                if (bean.isCategory())
                {
                    DisplayItem.Add(new ItemList { WidgetName = displayName[i], Icon = icons[i], arrow = arrowImage });
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayItem.Add(new ItemList { WidgetName = displayName[i], Icon = icons[i] });
                }
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("UI");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(TAG,e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}